# Can I debug a single thread in Visual Studio (2019) without freezing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is it possible to debug a single thread in Visual Studio 2019 Professional without freezing the other threads?

Comment: You could use a conditional breakpoint if there is a specific condition that applies to one of the threads

Comment: If there are any shared resources or other inter-thread comms etc. I can't really see why you'd want to, sounds like a headache.   Either use conditional breakpoints as suggested by @phuzi or simply use logging to try to see what's going on....